# ReadProcessMemory always reads 0

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, reverse-engineering

I'm creating a cheat for educational purpose (on windows for now) on a small game. My error is so far is that `ReadProcessMemory` always reads 0.

```cpp
LPCVOID addr = (LPCVOID *) 0x1228A93C; // TO-DO: c++ casts 
int dest = 0;
SIZE_T read = 0;
bool error = ReadProcessMemory(process, addr, &dest, sizeof(int), &read);
if (!error) {
    printf("I read %llu w/ %u at %p\r\n", read, dest, addr);
} else {
    printf("This isn't working: %p / %llu\r\n", addr, read);
    std::cerr << "err: " << std::to_string(::GetLastError()) << std::endl;
    return (1);
}
```

There, I try to read the amount on money in the game. By using Cheat Engine, I get the value that changes everytime you use your money which is `0x1228A93C` in the code snippet above. If I change the value pointed by this address in cheat engine, the money also change in game so I guess this is right address.

Nonetheless when I run this snippet, I get this output:

```
I read 0 w/ 0 at 0x1228a93c
```

which means it doesn't read.

**Note:** There is more code, in my program, above this one but this is basically finding the game window, create a snapshot of the game and find the exe module.

Comment: Please read about what [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) actually return.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `DWORD` (the return type of `GetLastError`) is an unsigned 32-bit integer, for which there exists overloads of the C++ stream output operator `<<`. Which means you don't need that `std::to_string`.

Comment: `BOOL` return values for an operation are almost always true on success, so it should be `bool success` and `if (success)`.

Comment: Most probably there is issue with access rights: "The handle must have PROCESS_VM_READ access to the process."

Comment: Where and how do you assign `process`?

Comment: @user253751 From the reference I linked to: `BOOL ReadProcessMemory(...)`. So yes it returns a `BOOL`, where `TRUE` is success.

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory` returns zero on failure. That gets covered to `false` when assigned to `error`. So now `error` is `false` on error and the expression `!error` is `true` on failure. At this point you outsmarted yourself to the point where you no longer understand *your* code. In other words: The call fails and reports an error. Now if you move on to call `GetLastError` it will return a meaningless value, because you're calling it too late. Use C if you aren't a big fan of invisible code.

Comment: I missread the `ReadProcessMemory` documentation, my bad. Thanks for pointing out that.
I just double checked the documentation for other Windows function I use. I'm not familiar at all with Windows functions.
Thanks you all for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
LPCVOID addr = (LPCVOID *) 0x1228A93C; // TO-DO: c++ casts 
int dest = 0;
SIZE_T read = 0;
if (ReadProcessMemory(process, addr, &dest, sizeof(int), &read))
{
    printf("I read %llu w/ %u at %p\r\n", read, dest, addr);
} else {
    auto lasterror = ::GetLastError();               // first thing to do: call GetLastError
    printf("This isn't working: %p / %llu\r\n", addr, read);
    std::cerr << "err: " << lasterror << std::endl;  // std::to_string is useless here
}
```

In case of error the first thing to do is call `GetLastError()` because you don't know if `cout` will call `SetLastError()` or not.